# Changing array to display the_title Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have

```
    <?php 
    $attr = array(
        'title' => 'here is a title',
        'alt' => 'here is a alt attribute'
    );
?>
    div class="s-o-column">
        <div class="s-o-thumb"><a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'standard-options-thumb',  false, $attr  ); ?></a>
        <div class="s-o-title"><a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I change it so the title and alt are say; `<?php the_title(); ?>` instead of "here is a title" or "here is a alt attribute"?

Comment: Can you be little more clear about your question.. I am still not getting it..

Comment: Well, the numbnails are now displayed with the title and alts provided in the array, I want, however the array to detect the post title, or the title of the thumbnail and place that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) instead of [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) since `get_the_title()` returns the title while `the_title()` echoes it.

```
$attr = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'alt' => 'here is a alt attribute'
);
```